# Toolbar TextColor and Overflow Menu color issue with Lollipop and Pre Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-toolbar

**Style**

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

**layout**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

By applying the above theme, `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`,

in `AppBar`, The Toolbar TextColor and Toolbar items are white in lollipop and black color in pre lollipop.

**Lollipop**

[image]

**Pre Lollipop**

[image]

And by applying the following theme, `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

The Toolbar Textcolor and Overflow Icon becomes black in both Lollipop and pre lollipop devices.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Lollipop**

[image]

**Pre Lollipop**

[image]

How can I work out to get Toolbar TextColor and OverFlow Menu icon color to white?? As you seen in the above code, I  used

`app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

and

`android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

But it didn't work out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of AppCompat/Design Library are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake 22.2.1, tried with 23 also, same problem

Comment: @DroidLearner have you go the solution

Answer (score 4):

This works for me!

```
<style name="AppTheme.WithoutActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/titleBarColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionBarColor</item>\
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

In manifest!

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WithoutActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to apply `ThemeOverlay` to the `Toolbar` itself (I'm not sure it even works on `AppBarLayout`, last time I checked, in support lib it only worked for `Toolbar`)

So, add this attribute to your `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

and it should all come into place, no extra text color tweaks needed.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. Prev version of AppCompat library worked. And ChrisBanes material example uses the same https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml#L35   And I dont know who down voted it

Comment: @DroidLearner Hm, weird, I'll try when I have some free time, I have a project that does this, I wonder if newer support lib will break it.

Comment: Hmm, I followed exactly this https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare. Didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

The best way to force the title, subtitle, colours from actiobar, toolbar, etc is by using html code.

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>ActionBarTitle </font>"));
```

Do the same with other titles. This way, it doesn't matter which theme you use or SDK, it will always be white.

Answer (score 0):

Make own text style and set it to the `Tollbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        [...]
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title.MyStyle" />
```

style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title.MyStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">

    <!-- Set title color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add these below lines in your `styles.xml` or `theme.xml` in values and values-v21 folder aswell

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark_color</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>         
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```